# Is Azure Web App billing by App Service?

Tags: azure, billing

If i have 3 web apps using the same "App Service plan/pricing tier", will I be billed by the 3 web apps + App Service, the 3 Web Apps or the App Service plan?

I could not reproduce this scenario on the calculator...

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudWhenDoAzureWebsitesMakeSense.aspx - a good resource on Azure Web Apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are billed for the App Service Plan, and you can run between 100 and unlimited sites ([depending on tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/app-service/)) per App Service Plan.